# how to fuzzy query in mysql ? 1 table 10GB data,8KW records

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

i have a table tbdb.ratedat,10GB size,8KW records,structure:

```
mysql> DESC ratedat;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| trade_id    | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| trade_time  | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| uid_buy     | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| uid_sell    | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| goods_title | varchar(120)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| goods_price | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rate_txt    | text          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**the structure of rate_buyer**

```
mysql> DESC rate_buyer;
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid       | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sex       | tinyint(1)    | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| costsum   | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| costavg   | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| costmax   | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| costmin   | decimal(12,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| costcount | int(10)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| timefirst | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timelast  | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| is_seller | tinyint(1)    | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| uptime    | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i want this result,search anykeywords list the distinct uid_sell from tbdb.ratedat:

```
SELECT a.*,b.goods_title,b.goods_price,COUNT(b.trade_id) AS relike
FROM rate_buyer a 
INNER JOIN ratedat b ON a.uid=b.uid_buy 
WHERE b.goods_title LIKE '%MP3%' 
GROUP BY a.uid ORDER BY relike DESC LIMIT 0 , 100 ;
```

but the size of tbdb.ratedat is over 10GB, when i run the sql ,program run time out.
what can i do to get the result like that sql?

Answer (score 1):

Use [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index. E.g.:

```
create fulltext index fulltext_goods_title on ratedat (goods_title);

select * from ratedat WHERE MATCH (goods_title) AGAINST ('MP3');
```

Comment: thank you very much,but the content of ratedat.goods_title is UTF8, may be chinese or japanese,not all are ANSI(english/number).mysql is not support chinese fulltext .(my system is WIN)

Comment: +1 but from the link "Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables"

Comment: Mario, what makes you think fulltext only works with ANSI charset. Actually it works with UTF8 charset too. That is, it works with Chinese/Japanese text. I admit You may need a few tricks to make it work, like set the minimum word length to 1 character or set the separator characters properly (or replace UTF8 separators with ANSI space in your texts).